Is there a video or audio lesson explaining the Mittler Rebbe's Sharei Emunah?
BH
Does anyone know if there a video or audio lesson explaining the Mittler Rebbe's Sharei Emunah, the first book in Torah Mitzvah Ve Torah Or?

This channel has some in Hebrew, but it looks incomplete.

you can find shaar hayichud of the mittler rebbe here: https://www.youtube.com/@truekabbalah6459/videos
